# Setting values in componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs

Is it a good or a bad idea to set some values in `componentWillMount()` method in a React component?

Say, I have a controlled component that is linked to an object. I receive some values through props and need to set them in the object. It looks something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }

   componentWillMount() {

       // I receive "color" through props and need to set it
       // in my object which is done through an action
       this.props.actions.setColor(this.props.color);
   }

   render() {
      return(
         <div>
             // Some stuff here
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Trying to determine the best time/place to set this value. Ultimately, I need the value in `myObject` and receive the value through props.

Trying to see if handling this in `componentWillMount()` is a good idea or not.

Comment: are you using react in the backend too? if so willmount will get called in the backend too.

Comment: No, only on the front-end. My back end is ASP.NET Core.

Comment: You had mentioned that `I receive "color" through props`. If the respective prop is available right from the beginning then setting in constructor is good place. If you receive it at later point of time, then set it in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea if the call has side effects e.g updating a store. From the docs for [`componentWillMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount):

> `componentWillMount()` is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before `render()`, therefore setting state synchronously in this method will not trigger a re-rendering. **Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.**

Also `componentWillMount` may be called several times e.g. server side rendering. You should use [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) instead.

On the other hand if the call has no side effects, you should move the call to your constructor instead.